# c# create a user control on button press, won't show

Tags: c#, user-controls, visual-studio-2013

```
counters.Add(new Counter());
foreach (Counter con in counters)
{
   con.Show();
   con.Top = this.Top;
   con.Left = this.Left;
}
```

counter is a very basic `UserControl` I made with 3 `buttons` and `textbox`. I'm trying create a draggable Counter, I can see the counter on the list (counters) but I can't see it anywhere on screen.

I was wondering if `new Counter()` is enough to create the  `UserControl` on screen.
(i mean to create this "counter" object dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control needs to have a parent that hosts the control. The parent control can be either a form or another container control. When you want to add your control to the hosting control, add the instance into the Controls collection of the hosting control like this:

```
var counter = new Counter();
var form = new Form();
form.Controls.Add(counter);
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think user Controls need to be in some sort of container, for example a flowLayoutPanel or your instance of the Form class itself to visually exist. 
You need to call CONTAINERINSTANCE.Controls.Add(con).